# What is the size of a recursive structure?

Tags: c

```
struct thing { 
    int x;
    thing* next;
}
```

The size is, obviously, `sizeof(int)+sizeof(thing*)`, but what is `sizeof(thing*)`???? Well, it's the size of a pointer to a structure that holds an int plus the size of a pointer to another structure which holds an int and a pointer to another structure which is the size of ................

So I guess the size of thing must be infinite. (This is what happens when a Mathematics major picks up a programming book. He takes everything to its logical extreme and gets confused.)

Comment: I get where you're coming from, though. I thought the same thing when I first started learning C.

Answer (score 2):

#### Size of structures

Note that the `thing *` you refer to is 100% unrelated to `struct thing`.  This is C; your tags say so.  You might write this to make the code compile cleanly:

```
typedef struct thing thing;
struct thing
{
    int    x;
    thing *next;
};
```

The minimum size of `struct thing` is `sizeof(int) + sizeof(thing *)`, but the structure can be bigger than that.  Indeed, on my (64-bit) machine, the structure is of size 16 bytes, even though `sizeof(int)` is just 4.  That's because addresses must be 8-byte aligned, so there are 4 bytes of padding between the `int` and the pointer.

#### 8-byte alignment

> Can you explain what "8-byte aligned" means?

Many CPUs require that an N-byte basic type should be stored at an address that is a multiple of N. Thus, 1-byte `char` variables can be stored at any address, but a 2-byte `short` variable must be stored at an address that is a multiple of 2, a 4-byte `int` variable must be stored at an address that is a multiple of 4, etc.  For some machines, especially RISC architectures, you get a SIGBUS signal (and core dump) if you try to read on the wrong alignment.  For others, you end up with the CPU doing multiple reads and bit twiddling to get the right result, but much more slowly than if the data had been correctly aligned.  Compilers know these are expensive and ensure that they do not break the rules.  And compilers introduce padding into structures if necessary, anywhere except at the start of the structure, to ensure that the elements within a structure are properly aligned, and that the elements of an array of the structure type will be properly aligned.

Consider a 64-bit compiler and the data structure:

```
struct list
{
    struct list *next;
    int          data;
};
```

Even though a single `struct list` could be just 12 bytes (8 bytes for the pointer, 4 bytes for the data), the compiler will add 4 bytes of padding at the end so that if you have an array of these structures, the starting address of the second item in the array will be correctly aligned on a multiple of 8 bytes (needed because addresses are 64-bit, 8-byte quantities).

#### Infinite size

> The size is, obviously, sizeof(int)+sizeof(thing*), but what is sizeof(thing*)???? Well, it's the size of a pointer to a structure that holds an int plus the size of a pointer to another structure which holds an int and a pointer to another structure which is the size of ................
>
> So I guess the size of thing must be infinite.

There's no infinite regress here.  The size of a structure and the size of a pointer to a structure are two very different things.  C does not allow recursive types:

```
struct xyz { int data; struct xyz nested; };   /* Invalid C and C++ and ... */
```

This would require an infinite amount of memory, which even virtual memory cannot simulate (there aren't enough bits in the main memory of the computer to hold the size of an infinitely large data structure, much less the infinitely large structure itself).

But the structure in the question doesn't contain a structure; it contains a pointer to a structure.  The C standard guarantees that all addresses for structures are the same size (POSIX places more stringent requirements — all pointers to all objects and pointers to functions must be the same size).  So the size of a pointer to a structure is fixed — 4 bytes for 32-bit compilations, and 8 bytes for 64-bit compilations (in practice, even if there could theoretically be exceptions).  And the size of the structure is fixed and finite.

Comment: Huh, so on your system, a struct with two `chars` is also 8?

Comment: @DennisMeng: No; `sizeof(struct { char a; char b; })` is 2.  `char` can be aligned on any byte boundary, so there's no padding needed.  For the record, this is Mac OS X 10.9 and GCC 4.8.2, compiling in 64-bit mode (the default).  With 32-bit compilation, the `struct thing` would be just 8 bytes because the 32-bit pointers only need to be 4-byte aligned, not 8-byte aligned.

Comment: Ah okay. Guess I misread what you said, sounds like your system does what I'm used to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Can you explain what "8-byte aligned" means?

Comment: For a variable to be aligned means that its address in memory is a multiple of some constant. Some processors can only access variables that are aligned on their own size (8 bytes alignment for a 64bit pointer). Some other may perform better if so.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no, `sizeof(struct thing*)` is just the size of a pointer required to point to the structure, *not* anything that might be in the structure. (Consider the case of a null pointer, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

No, pointers are of fixed size.  So the size of thing is sizeof (int) + sizeof (pointer).

Nitpicker's corner:

The size of a pointer in commonly encountered CPU architectures is either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the CPU architecture.

However, some uncommon architectures (DSP chips, oddball microcontrollers, PDP-10 and other word-oriented architectures) have differently sized pointers.

In addition, in some uncommon architectures, pointers to differently sized objects are themselves of different sizes, so, for example, sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*).

Furthermore, some architectures allow bit-oriented addressing, so that one can take addresses of bitfields, which is not often allowed.  (This is not allowed by the C Standard, but it can be done as a vendor extension.)

Comment: Or 16 bytes if `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(thing *)` is 8 and pointers must be aligned on an 8-byte boundary.

Comment: The C standard does not require all pointers to be the same size. The size of a pointer may depend on what it points to. However, since pointers to incomplete types may be defined, the size of a pointer to a struct must be fixed. It may be different from the size of a pointer to `int`, for example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I'm aware of that.  There's the 99% case, and then there's the weird hairballs (PDP-10, odd DSP chips, etc). I (perhaps unwisely) assumed this was the 99% case.

Comment: StackOverflow is intended to be a repository of questions and answers for general reference. If you answer a question for a specific assumption, without stating that assumption, the answer is defective for other users.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hence the statement "usually".  It's times like this that I empathize with Steven Den Beste.

Comment: @EricBrown: The “usually” says the size is usually four or eight bytes, not that the size is usually fixed. It is not hard to improve this answer rather than defend a position you know is incorrect. Why not edit instead or argue?

Answer (score 1):

The size of a pointer does not rely in any way on what it is a pointer *to*. The pointer will be the size of a word, so either 4 or 8 bytes, for your system.

Comment: The C standard does not require all pointers to be the same size. The size of a pointer may depend on what it points to. However, since pointers to incomplete types may be defined, the size of a pointer to a struct must be fixed. It may be different from the size of a pointer to `int`, for example.